# React Render Array in Mapped Return

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reactjs

I have a react component that is rendering some results. The problem I am having is with result.participants. This is an array, so map is rendering both names without any spacing and I am finding it difficult to get those spaces inserted.

The result.participants is an array of strings.

How do I insert a space or some logic to put in a comma and a space if the length is >1 ?

```
render: function(){
  return (
  <ul>
    {
      this.state.pads.map(function(result){
        return [
        <a href={result.pageUrl}>{result.title}</a>,
        <li key={result.participants}>Participants: {result.participants} </li>,
        <li key={result.summary}>Summary: {result.summary}</li>,
        <li key={result.lastEdit}>Last Edited: {new Date(result.lastEdit).toDateString()} </li>,
        <p></p>
        ];
      })}
  </ul>
)
}
```

Comment: [According to HTML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html#ul-content-model), you don't suppose to have `<p>` and `<a>` directly inside `<ul>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like a commenter mentioned, you should not put bare `<a>` and `<p>` tags into a `<ul>` directly. But that is beside the point, this question is about array handling in React.

You should be able to use a control flow structure nested in JSX like this:

```
{
  result.participants.map(function(participant, idx) {
    if (idx == result.participants.length - 1) {
      return (
        <span>{participant}, </span>
      );
    } else {
      return participant;
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: you could alternatively do `function(participant, idx, array){ if (idx === array.length) ...`.  I prefer it because you can then extract that function and use it in multiple contexts without changing anything.

Answer (score 4):

And if you don't care about wrapping each participant in a `<span>`, you could simply use the built-in `Array.prototype.join` method:

`<li key={result.participants}>Participants: {result.participants.join(', ')} </li>,`