# React render array returned from map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, promise, reactjs, lodash

I am facing a very similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674704/react-render-array-in-mapped-return), but I am fetching data using a Promise and want to render it into the DOM when it comes through. The `console.log()` displays all the items correctly. I think my problem is that the lodash.map returns an array of `<li>` elements, and so I am trying to call `this.renderItems()` in order to render (but `renderItems()` doesn't seem to exist). Am I doing something unconventional, is there an easier way, is there an equivalent function to replace my `renderItems()`?

```
   renderArticleHeadline: function(article) {
      console.log('renderArticleHeadline', article.headline);
      return (
         <li>
            {article.headline}
         </li>
      )
   },
   render: function() {
      return (
         <div>
            <ul>
               {
                  this.renderItems(
                     this.fetchFrontPageArticles().then(data => {
                        lodash.map(data, this.renderArticleHeadline)
                     })
                  )
               }
            </ul>
         </div>
      );
   }
```

Comment: Remember that `render` is called synchronously, yet your `fetch` is async. So, the `render` function has already completed by the time your data has returned. So, nothing will show.

Comment: IIRC `render` should not call `fetch`, the control flow should be in the reverse direction.

Comment: @Bergi it's not so much an IIRC (React is just a view library) as common sense :) That said the issue here is probably that renderItems is fed a promise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be something like this

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        items: []
    };
},
renderArticleHeadline: function(article) {
    return (
         <li>
            {article.headline}
         </li>
    );
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.fetchFrontPageArticles().then(data => {
        this.setState({
            items: data
        });
    });
},
render: function() {
  var items = lodash.map(this.state.items, this.renderArticleHeadline);
  return (
     <div>
        <ul>
            {items}
        </ul>
     </div>
  );
}
```

P.S. read [thinking in react](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Comment: Yes this looks much more like it with fetchFrontPageArticles calling setState

Comment: FWIW newer React versions will probably complain if you don't have a key on the renderArticleHeadline <li> elements OR more properly move the <li> elements to another React class so that it can manage it as fragments.