# How can i iterate this json with map in React to render it

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Im trying to iterate this JSON so i can make a table, but as there is many headers and many data how can i go through without doing this.

```
 const BBDDCustomer = {
      ui_labels: {
        name: 'Name',
        address: 'address',
        postalCode: 'Postal Code',
        city: 'City',
        country: 'Country',
        telephone: 'Telephone',
        email: 'Email',
        modified: 'Modified',
        delete: 'Delete'

      },
  data: [
    {
      name: 'n1',
      address: 'a1',
      postalCode: 'PC 1',
      city: 'c 1',
      country: 'cou 1',
      telephone: 'tel 1',
      email: 'em 1'
    }
}
```

I don't have to write like this:

```
<table striped bordered condensed hover responsive>
      <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>{BBDDCustomer.ui_labels.name}</th>
         <th>{BBDDCustomer.ui_labels.address}</th>
         <th>{BBDDCustomer.ui_labels.postalCode}</th>
         <th>{BBDDCustomer.ui_labels.city}</th>
         <th>{BBDDCustomer.ui_labels.country}</th>
         <th>{BBDDCustomer.ui_labels.telephone}</th>
         <th>{BBDDCustomer.ui_labels.email}</th>
         <th>{BBDDCustomer.ui_labels.modified}</th>
         <th>{BBDDCustomer.ui_labels.delete}</th>
       </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: it's not *JSON* > [what?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: You can use `Object.keys` combined with `map`. But the order of properties is not guaranteed.

Comment: The answer is in the question, isnt it? map over your structure and render. You need to learn react to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Render Array in Mapped Return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674704/react-render-array-in-mapped-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enumerate properties in the order you want

```
const columns = ['name', 'address', ...];
```

and use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
<Table striped bordered condensed hover responsive>
      <thead>
       <tr>
           {
             columns.map(column => (
              <th key={column}>{BBDDCustomer.ui_labels[column]}</th>
            ))
           }
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {
          BBDDCustomer.data.map((data, i) =>(
           <tr key={i}>
               {
                 columns.map(column => (
                    <td key={column + i}>{data[column]}</td>
                 ))
               }
           </tr>
          ))
        }
      </tbody>
</Table>
```

Comment: Yury is spot on. Here is a variation of his approach: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/jrQZvA